# can't get the category ID ( java/sql )

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I have 2 tables:
salon_stock
categories

the salon_stock table has a fk column cat_id of categories table

Categories table have 2 columns cat_id & title

In the below code i am trying to insert the cat_id which belong to a category name 
retrieved from a JComboBox  along with the data of  salon_stock table

```
    private void AddStock() throws SQLException,NullPointerException {
```

int catID = 0;

String cat=cat_list.getSelectedItem().toString();

`if (cat.equals("Select a Category")) {
                 ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from categories where title=' Default'");

            if(rs.next()){
                catID=rs.getInt("cat_id");
            }
            else{
                throw new SQLException("The 'Default' category was not found in the Categories Table");
            }

            }
            else{
          ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from categories where title=' "+cat+"'");

            if(rs.next()){
               catID=rs.getInt("cat_id");
               }
            }

          ps1 = con.prepareStatement("insert into "+tableName+"(title,price,qty,cat_id) values( ?,?,?,?)");

          ps1.setString(1,title_field.getText());
          ps1.setInt(2,Integer.parseInt(price_field.getText()));
          ps1.setInt(3,Integer.parseInt(qty_field.getText()));
          ps1.setInt(4,catID);
          ps1.executeUpdate();
          ps1.closeOnCompletion();

    }`

the code runs fine but in the table, it inserts the '0' value to the cat_id column of stock_table.

i am unable to detect the error..
please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe the space in the query is the error:

```
"select * from categories where title=' "+cat+"'"
```

must be

```
"select * from categories where title='"+cat+"'"
```

Comment: then you could close the question

Comment: how do i close it ? should i delete it or flag it ?

Comment: near my answare in the top-left, there is a V check that become green on mouse over: click it

Comment: i did it; i did tried it long ago but i had to wait at least 8 mins ..any way thanks a lot that was a very quick response i ever had on stackoverflow